# HOw long for seo changes to take effect?>

Tags: seo, updates

I have a site that I submitted to google, did some of the webmaster tools things for (sitemap, preferred domain etc) and set up analytics for about a week ago.

Yesterday i made a pile of changes to the body text, and to the meta and title tags text.

Should I re-submit the site to google, and how long will it take for me to see any results from my experiments!

Many thanks

Comment: Google may have not crawled your website yet. There is no point to resubmit it again.

Comment: Thanks. When will I know if the changes have worked or not?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: That's why I tagged it seo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google may have not crawled your website yet. It may take 2 or 3 weeks.

From google support: Google's spiders regularly crawl the web to rebuild our index. Crawls are based on many factors such as PageRank, links to a page, and crawling constraints such as the number of parameters in a URL. Any number of factors can affect the crawl frequency of individual sites.

see also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897?hl=en

You will know it did when you start seeing statistics in your webmaster tools. It's more of a trial and error here.